# Unable to close flash[:notice] message using Bootstrap with Rails 4

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

Using Bootstrap 3 with a Rails 4 app, and I have set up flash[:notice], flash[:error], flash[:alert] in my `application.html.erb`file like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head> 
<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <ul class='nav nav-tabs'>
      <li><%= link_to 'Wikis', wikis_path %></li>
      <div class="pull-right user-info">
      <% if user_signed_in? %>
        Hello, <%= link_to current_user.name, edit_user_registration_path %> |
        <%= link_to 'Sign Out', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
     <% else %>
        <%= link_to 'Sign Up', new_user_registration_path %> or
        <%= link_to 'Sign In', user_session_path %>
     <% end %>
      </div>
   </ul>
 </div>

 <% if flash[:notice] %>
 <div class="alert alert-success">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
   <%= flash[:notice] %>
 </div>
 <% elsif flash[:error] %>
 <div class="alert alert-danger">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
   <%= flash[:error] %>
 </div>
 <% elsif flash[:alert] %>
 <div class="alert alert-warning">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
   <%= flash[:alert] %>
 </div>
 <% end %>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bootstsrap.min.js"></script>

 <%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

When I receive a notice, error, or alert in both my development and production applications, I am unable to close it out. I've tried moving the two `scrpt src` around, but it doesn't seem to have any impact.

Comment: Your alert is missing the `alert-dismissible` class.

Comment: There is a typo in the file name `js/bootstsrap.min.js`

Comment: @cvrebert I have ```class="close" data-dismiss="alert"```, I swapped ```class="close"``` out for ```class='alert-dismissable``` and while it changed the styling of the close object, I was still unable to actually close the alert.

Comment: @anpsmn nice spot. I updated this, however it didn't seem to have an impact. Still unable to close out the alert.

Comment: `alert-dismissible` goes with the `alert` class, not on the close button.

Comment: For anyone finding this question but you're having issues with Bootstrap 4 flash messages not closing and you're not avoiding java, be sure you follow the CSS and JS instructions from this page (solved my issues while following an outdated tutorial): https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update**: I was able to fix this by adding `//= require bootstrap` to my `application.js` file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 4, you don't need to require all of Bootstrap. If this is all the JS you need, just do:

```
//= require bootstrap/alert
//= require bootstrap/util
```